# ChildWindow Loading Issue in Prism 4.1 Silverlight 5 Telerik Application

Tags: silverlight, telerik, prism

In my RadGridView Column I've a button which is Bind to a DelegateCommand for this I want to Load a ChildWindow Popup (For now Silverlight ChildWindow May Be later TelerikWindowAs I'm looking for work around).
I'm trying to follow
http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/9676 but when I try to add code.

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding InteractionRequest}">
        <InteractionRequest:PopupInteractionRequestChildWindow>
            <InteractionRequest:PopupInteractionRequestChildWindow.ChildWindow>
                <Views:PrismMVVMChildWindow />
            </InteractionRequest:PopupInteractionRequestChildWindow.ChildWindow>
        </InteractionRequest:PopupInteractionRequestChildWindow>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

says Not found schema. I already added but after typing

```
 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
to 
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Inte‌​ractivity"
```

Says No dll found. 
After this I try addling Microsoft.Expression.Interactions in reference but no Success. it always say

```
<i: <Uunknow>>  error.
```

How to solve it. I'm working with Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference both `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` from the Lib\Desktop folder of the Prism distribution (assuming you're using Prism v4.x)